# Copying portion of applet screen into image

Tags: java, image, graphics, applet, awt

Are there any `java.awt.Graphics` methods that I can use to copy a rectangular portion of my current screen and store it as an image variable? If not what are the best alternatives I could use?

Comment: Are you attempting to capture the *current* screen, or the *applet's* display? This clarification is necessary.

Comment: I am trying to copy a portion of just the applet's display. I understand the robot class approach in the answer below, and have used it before, but I am looking to just find images in the applet.

Answer (score 2):

If the applet is signed and has enough permission, `java.awt.Robot` is available.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, displayMode.getWidth(), displayMode.getHeight());
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
```

Comment: This will only work if the applet's display is on top of all other windows, and this offers no cropping to a "portion of the applet screen".  While this answer may be a start, it is far from complete.